# Salty or fresh or brackish waters?

Tags: science-based, environment, water, rivers

[image: Parsas Decem land map]

So this is a small map of all the continents on the small planet of Parsas Decem. As far as most of the rivers go, I’ve got it figured out. What I’m wondering is, can salt water flowing in from the sea be filtered naturally by the soil, perhaps with specific desalinating minerals, into fresh water? If I can, I’ll try to post the map of just the north eastern quarter of Daichi.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand our community. Also, please use the edit function to edit your question, we are not a forum where you post below your initial post to further add information, this is why I have deleted your "answer". I also don't see the relation between your question and the image, so I would consider removing it.

Comment: No it cannot, and moreover you did not explain *why* you need this to happen: maybe there are other ways to solve the real problem.

Comment: Are you familiar with the history of the Baltic Sea since the last glacial maximum?  It has experienced all of these regimes.

Comment: On an off-note: you seem to have multiple rivers that are combined in- and outflows - is this by design or by accident? Usually water only flowa into one direction; streams join into one, becoming bigger; lakes have multiple inlets but only one outlet

Comment: For the most part water source comes down from the frigid snow of Akull which is fresh. There’s an area where it seems to flow into Rants which is a flooded swampy marshland, and then I suppose brackish water flows south from where they meet but I’m thinking I’ll need a lake there. I guess the river that comes in from beneath Walnot and Tachiki will have to be salty rivers.

Comment: Saltwater is not going to flow inland more than few dozen meters, ground water flowing out prevents it.

Comment: Why do you think you will have salt water flowing inland?

Answer (score 8):

Saltwater does not move far inland, **you are chasing a problem that doesn't exist**. Saltwater intrusion of more than a kilometer is all but unheard of, and then only in the driest locations and only affecting deep wells. Saltwater is also displaced outward and downward by fresh water, the fresh water is renewed by rain anywhere inland. Look at the lower picture an example of measured salt water intrusion. Saltwater permeating inland is measured in feet.

Unless you have and an inland sea that is not shown or have extreme flooding salt water intrusion is not an issue, and if you do that is a very different question.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> can salt water flowin in from the sea be filtered naturally by the soil, perhaps with specific desalinating minerals, into fresh water?

You are looking for a way to naturally [desalinize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desalination) water.

Sorry to disappoint you, but it requires energy to happen, thus I don't think it can happen by simple filtration.

> Desalination is a process that takes away mineral components from saline water.

The closes you can get in a natural environment is one of the following:

First reverse osmosis

> The leading process for desalination in terms of installed capacity and yearly growth is reverse osmosis (RO). The RO membrane processes use semipermeable membranes and applied pressure (on the membrane feed side) to preferentially induce water permeation through the membrane while rejecting salts. Reverse osmosis plant membrane systems typically use less energy than thermal desalination processes.

Or also freeze-taw

> Freeze-thaw desalination uses freezing to remove fresh water from salt water. Salt water is sprayed during freezing conditions into a pad where an ice-pile builds up. When seasonal conditions warm, naturally desalinated melt water is recovered. This technique relies on extended periods of natural sub-freezing conditions.

Or, finally, solar evaporation

> Solar evaporation mimics the natural water cycle, in which the sun heats the sea water enough for evaporation to occur. After evaporation, the water vapor is condensed onto a cool surface.

Comment: Well what if there were natural fresh springs feeding the rivers that start salty? Would you say it’s possible for the salt levels to become essentially negligible if there are enough fresh springs on the way? Or would the salt water likely always be salty? It’s fine if they’re not all fresh, I just need to know the lay of the land before any stories can happen around them

Comment: @BetteStruble, this is a different question than what you asked. You asked about filtration, not dilution.

Comment: if there is a natural spring your river will not be salty.

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is not what you asked for, but you could find it interesting
[This article](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/10/easter-islands-statue-builders-sort-of-drank-from-the-sea/) explains that for the ancient Easter Island populations, the main water sources were brackish-water pools near the sea.

> the Rapanui probably got at least some of their drinking water from places along the coast where fresh groundwater seeped out of the island’s bedrock and into the sea. The resulting mixture would have been brackish but safe to drink, and it could have sustained populations of thousands on an island with few other reliable sources of fresh water

I know that it is not a desalinization of sea water (of course it is the opposite, the partial salinization of underground water), but it could sustain some settlements along the coast and far from rivers, if the soil is too hard to dig wells far from the sea.
And if the brackish water has a bad taste, you can always use it to brew beer :)

Answer (score 1):

### It depends on where you are on the Coastline

How far inland salt water permeates depends largely on what kind of coastline a region has.  In general, you have 4 kinds of coastlines to worry about.

#### Coastal Ridges

A Coastal Ridge will generally form in lowlands where there is no significant amount of surface fresh water spilling out into the ocean.  In these places, the waves of the sea build up a sand bank over time that prevents the ocean water from going more than a few meters inland, and fresh ground water displaces the salty groundwater. John's answer describes this kind of shoreline pretty well.  So places like Ekrixi and Northern Daichi will probably follow these rules meaning that most wells or inland ponds should be a viable source of freshwater as long as your population is not so high that agriculture depletes the freshwater table allowing salt water to permeate farther into the water table than it naturally should.

#### River Deltas

These areas are the mouths of major rivers in lowland areas.  How far up the river salt water mixes depends on how fast moving the water is. During your dry seasons, the waters will slow down and drop allowing salt water to move farther up the river whereas in rainy seasons the fresh water will wash out the salt water.  In most rivers, the brashish zone is only a few kilometers, but in some parts of the world, it can extend inland for over 100km.  Flater, dryer regions like Erismost will have the most issue with salt water coming up the rivers, but what they can do is wait for the rains to wash the salt water out.  Collect the fresh water into large reservoirs, and then live off of the saved fresh water during the dry season when thier rivers become salty again.

#### Sea Cliffs

Sea cliffs are places where the ground is higher than the sea where they meet.  In these places, you don't have to worry about salt water intrusion at all, even where rivers meet the sea because the rivers pour into the ocean instead of mixing with it like they do in a delta region.  The biggest risk of living in a sea cliff region is that your fresh water table may be very deep and hard to get too; so, wells may not be a viable option at all which could force your populations to hug tighter to the rivers and lakes than they would in most low land coastline areas. You see this a lot around volcanic or mountainous coastlines; so, Ciroccd and Ekrixi should probably have a fair number of Sea Cliffs.

#### Wetlands

These are your real wildcards.  In some low lying places where natural forces prevent the formation of strong natural ridge lines, you get frequent flooding of salt water into the inland area.  In some cases, these swampy areas are only mildly brackish and safe enough to drink, but in some places they can become sumps for saltwater and become even more salty than the ocean itself as the water will evaporate leaving salt behind in between each flood.  Salty wetlands can extend inland for 10s of kilometers.  Wetlands in general are not ideal places for human settlements, even if the water is safe to drink.  West-Central Daichi will probably have a fair amount of coastal wetlands; so, you will want to put all your settlements at least 30-50km inland with only the odd trappers and fishermen living out in the actual wetlands.  They will need to get thier fresh water from boiling or imported, but this should not be a huge problem since wetland populations tend to be so small and rich in vegetation that there should be plenty of wood to burn per inhabitant for the boiling of water.

Answer (score 0):

Well no, but...
Salt water is more dense than fresh. If you have a difficult region for wells, say very sandy or otherwise unable to keep wells from crumbling, you could flood the area with salt water that would sink and raise up the fresh water which could be harvested off the top.

(might have to do this experiment myself: take a pot or bucket and fill it one quarter with fresh water and then halfway with sand (so that sand is basically wet but no way to take a straw and suck out just water); then add seawater until it displaces the freshwater which rises above the sand and can be siphoned off)

I don't know the long term viability of this plan but as long as the ground is saturated with the seawater all the rain or aquifer seepage will be on top and able to be collected.

Comment: You need something to prevent salt following the concentration gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Already said, desalination requires energy. I would also add that if any subsoil filtering system exists, where does the salt go to? From your description, it must accumulate until the filtration system is no longer operable. The inhabitants must have mined that salt on a regular basis, but that necessitates some mining technology, as well as knowing about such filtration system in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pbs.org/newshour/nation/why-salt-water-is-threatening-drinking-water-in-new-orleans-and-what-officials-are-doing-about-it

Seems they disagree with how far saltwater goes up a river. We had always heard the CT river was brackish well up the river due to moon, winds, tides, storms, hutricanes.  Also a question is how much pressure us required to force saltwater through a media ( river bottom... sand, mud, etc) to filtrate salt from saltwater. And how do desalinization bottles work without power?